# Moving to a part of webpage after page refresh

Tags: php, jquery, forms, validation, anchor

I have a list of comments for a given article and I have a form underneath the comments for a user to add their own comments.

I'm using php to do some form validation.

This is the process:

1. User fills out form (or not) and hits submit button. page refreshes.
2. PHP validates user input and either submits comments if no errors or
   generates a list of errors.
3. If errors exist display the errors.

   The problem is that I want the errors to display underneath the comments before the form which it does but when th epage refreshes, the top of the page is displayed and i need  it to go straight to the errors and form (much like a page anchor)

Is this possible?

This is called after the submit button is clicked

```
if(empty($errors)){
        $result = post_comment('event',$event_id, $sendername, $senderemail, $userurl, $comment);
        if ($result == 'Correct') {
            //header('Location: /'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
            header('Location: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        }
        else {
            $send_error = $result;
```

and this is near the comments and form where i want to page to go to if errors exist

```
// If there was an error sending the email, display the error message
if (isset($send_error)) {
echo "<a name=\"commentsform\"></a>";
echo "There was an error: ".$send_error;
}
/**
* If there are errors and the number of errors is greater than zero,
* display a warning message to the user with a list of errors
*/
if ( isset($errors) && count($errors) > 0 ) {
    echo ( "<h2 class='errorhead'>There has been an error:</h2><p><span class='bold'>You forgot to enter the following field(s)</span></p>" );
    echo ( "<ul id='validation'>\n" );
    foreach ( $errors as $error ) {
        echo ( "<li>".$error."</li>\n" );
    }
echo ( "</ul>\n" );
}
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use the native browser ability to jump to an id if the url's hash matches: `example.com#id` will go to http://example.com and jump to the element with id of `id`

Answer (score 1):

Give the form an ID which can be jumped to via the URL:

```
<div id="submitComment">
  <!-- Comment form here -->
</div>
```

And then redirect the user back to the same URL with the appropriate hash tag:

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com#submitComment');
```

Comment: It should: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3. Whether it actually does or not is another question.

Answer (score 1):

Find your form tag, it will look something like this

```
<form action='yourpage.php'>
```

Put a hash tag after the URL along with the anchor it will go to upon submission-

```
<form action='yourpage.php#commentsform'>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using page anchors you can jump the user to any part of the page by changing the hash in the url.

Make the form send the user to to anchor like so:

```
<form action='yourpage.php#comments'>
```

And make an anchor where you want your user to end up:

```
<a name="comments"></a>
```